# angular slick grid complex object with nullable string

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I am using angular slickgrid

```
  { id: 'fullName', field: 'user.fullName', name: 'Agent Name', filterable: true, sortable: true, formatter: Formatters.complexObject },
```

Error shows only if fullname is nullable data from json exist  i am getting below

> ```
> EDIT:
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
>     at getCanvasWidth (vendor.js:195836)
>     at getViewportHeight (vendor.js:198686)
>     at SlickGrid.resizeCanvas (vendor.js:198712)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGridWithDimensions (vendor.js:94087)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGridCallback (vendor.js:94061)
>     at vendor.js:94053
>     at timer (polyfills.js:13097)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:10942)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:43226)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:10941)
> defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6456
> handleError @ core.js:6504
> next @ core.js:29284
> __tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
> next @ Subscriber.js:122
> _next @ Subscriber.js:72
> next @ Subscriber.js:49
> next @ Subject.js:39
> emit @ core.js:25946
> (anonymous) @ core.js:28703
> invoke @ zone.js:372
> run @ zone.js:134
> runOutsideAngular @ core.js:28576
> onHandleError @ core.js:28703
> handleError @ zone.js:376
> runTask @ zone.js:181
> invokeTask @ zone.js:487
> ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:476
> data.args.<computed> @ zone.js:2541
> core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>     at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
>     at complexObjectFormatter (vendor.js:101862)
>     at appendCellHtml (vendor.js:198432)
>     at appendRowHtml (vendor.js:198386)
>     at renderRows (vendor.js:199153)
>     at render (vendor.js:199258)
>     at resizeCanvas (vendor.js:198814)
>     at updateRowCount (vendor.js:198910)
>     at SlickGrid.invalidate (vendor.js:198490)
>     at DataView.<anonymous> (vendor.js:103566)
> defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6456
> core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
>     at ensureCellNodesInRowsCache (vendor.js:198967)
>     at cleanUpAndRenderCells (vendor.js:199053)
>     at render (vendor.js:199254)
>     at SlickGrid.resizeCanvas (vendor.js:198814)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGridWithDimensions (vendor.js:94087)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGridCallback (vendor.js:94061)
>     at vendor.js:94056
>     at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:11923)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGrid (vendor.js:94048)
>     at ResizerService.handleResizeGrid (vendor.js:93949)
>     at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:11749)
>     at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:11926)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGrid (vendor.js:94048)
>     at ResizerService.handleResizeGrid (vendor.js:93949)
>     at dispatch (scripts.js:5430)
>     at $event.dispatch (scripts.js:11280)
>     at $event.dispatch (vendor.js:187486)
>     at elemData.handle (scripts.js:5234)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:10942)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:43226)
> defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6456
> core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
>     at ensureCellNodesInRowsCache (vendor.js:198967)
>     at cleanUpAndRenderCells (vendor.js:199053)
>     at render (vendor.js:199254)
>     at SlickGrid.resizeCanvas (vendor.js:198814)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGridWithDimensions (vendor.js:94087)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGridCallback (vendor.js:94061)
>     at vendor.js:94056
>     at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:11923)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGrid (vendor.js:94048)
>     at ResizerService.handleResizeGrid (vendor.js:93950)
>     at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:11749)
>     at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills.js:11926)
>     at ResizerService.resizeGrid (vendor.js:94048)
>     at ResizerService.handleResizeGrid (vendor.js:93950)
>     at dispatch (scripts.js:5430)
>     at $event.dispatch (scripts.js:11280)
>     at $event.dispatch (vendor.js:187486)
>     at elemData.handle (scripts.js:5234)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:10942)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:43226)
> ```

Above error getting only for complex object with null data ..Pleas let me how to configure.
@gistcode i have added more error log..Please check,,Can you please provide how i can i convert cutom format for this use case

Comment: you could try this flag `cellValueCouldBeUndefined` from the grid option and see if that works, this should also help for the sorting. If that doesn't work you can create your own Custom Formatter OR contribute a fix but now I just released a new major version 3.0 and this code now exist in Slickgrid-Universal

Comment: @ghiscoding thanks..i will try 3 try new release..

Comment: you can try converting to the new version but the code will be the same, the `cellValueCouldBeUndefined` will result in the same thing in both version, I would suggest you try it before converting to the new version. I'm saying this because there a few steps to follow to migrate to the new version, you can see all about it in the [Release](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases) section. It might help also for you to click on the `complexObjectFormatter` and see exactly which line of the formatter throws the error bcoz line 18369 doesn't tell me anything in minified code

Comment: cellValueCouldBeUndefined  didnot work...how to write custom format ? can u pls provide a  link for how i can i do that..i have added moe error log in the question...

Comment: You're showing a completely different error now which is unrelated to the ComplexObjectFormatter. Anyway here's the [Custom Formatter Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Formatters#custom-formatter), and here's the link to the [ComplexObjectFormatter](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/version2/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/formatters/complexObjectFormatter.ts) if you want to copy the code and modify it as a Custom Formatter

Comment: Thanks..am new to frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

That was a bug that I was able to replicate and I just pushed a [PR fix](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/pull/816) to address the issue and also released a new patch version `2.30.5` (the fix will also be available in latest major version `3.x`). Just update to version `2.30.5` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much dude..I will check .since morning I am trying ...but goto know that of in my case if user itself null then grid was populated...only user.fullname if null it throws error..any way thanks anks again for fixing